# Recursive Function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have a recusive function that is supposed to loop through a json object and output the expression. However, my recusion seems to be off because it's outputting **field1 != '' AND field3 == ''** when it should be outputting **field1 != '' AND field2 == '' AND field3 == ''**

I've tried a couple different things and the only way I can get it to work is by creating a global variable `outstring` instead of passing it to the function. Where am I off? When I step through it, i see a correct result but once the stack reverses, it start resetting `outstring` and then stack it back up again but leaves out the middle (field2).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rs4zqmya/1/)

```
function buildString(json, outstring) {
        var andor = json.condition;
    for (var rule in json.rules) {
        if (json.rules[rule].hasOwnProperty("condition")) {
            buildString(json.rules[rule], outstring);
        } else {
            var field = json.rules[rule].id;
            var operator = json.rules[rule].operator;
            var value = json.rules[rule].value == null ? '' : json.rules[rule].value;
            outstring += field + ' ' + operator + ' ' + value;
            if (rule < json.rules.length - 1) {
                outstring += ' ' + andor + ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    return outstring;
}

var jsonObj = {"condition":"AND","rules":[{"id":"field1","operator":"!= ''","value":null},{"condition":"AND","rules":[{"id":"field2","operator":"== ''","value":null}]},{"id":"field3","operator":"== ''","value":null}]};

$('#mydiv').text(buildString(jsonObj, ""));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function has a return of a string.

When you call the function recursively from within itself, you aren't doing anything with the returned string from that instance, just calling the function which has nowhere to return to

Change:

```
    if (json.rules[rule].hasOwnProperty("condition")) {
       buildString(json.rules[rule], outstring);
    }
```

To

```
    if (json.rules[rule].hasOwnProperty("condition")) {
       // include the returned value in concatenated string
       outstring += buildString(json.rules[rule], outstring);
    }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rs4zqmya/2/)

Comment: actually it's `outstring = buildString(json.rules[rule], outstring)` or `outstring += buildString(json.rules[rule], "")`

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?

```
function buildString(obj) {
    return "condition" in obj?
        obj.rules.map(buildString).join(" " + obj.condition + " "):
        obj.id + " " + obj.operator + " " + string(obj.value);
}

//this problem occurs quite often, write a utility-function.
function string(v){ return v == null? "": String(v) }
```